# Не передается порт MYSQL в контейнер

Tags: mysql, docker

Ошибка bind: address already in use. Это возможно без вынесения MYSQL в отдельный контейнер?

Если сначала стартовать MYSQL, то контейнер с php-fpm при пробросе порта напишет что адрес уже используется, если сначала стартовать контейнер то MYSQL не запускается.

Comment: В docker-compose.yml пробросьте порты) зависимость контейнера от контейнера там.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456780/run-mysql-on-port-3307-using-docker-compose

Comment: В том то и дело что мне хотелось разобраться как это сделать без docker-compose, но вот на этом месте я впал в ступор. Чисто из интереса

Comment: Можно и без файлика.. при запуске в консоле ключи прописать можно

Comment: так я и прописал соответствие портов, он мне выдал ошибку что адрес уже испльзуется

Comment: В общем пока решение не нашел, если все в контейнерах то информации куча как сделать, а если одно в контейнере, а другое слушает IP не в контейнере (php-fpm например), то прокинуть порт в контейнер с nginx не получается, пишет что порт занят

Comment: Если ты хочешь, чтобы ПХП из контейнера коннектился к МайСКЛ на хосте, то это достигается не пробрасываением портов. Пробрасывание требуется ровно для обратной задачи - соединение с хоста с портом внутри Докера.

Comment: Чтобы изнутри Докера приконнектится к порту на хосте, надо использовать ИП адрес хоста, ну и кой-какую настройку МайСКЛ провести, см https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57500887/how-to-access-host-mysql-server-in-a-docker-container

Comment: Читал про host.docker.internal, у меня не заработало, и я подумал что это адрес докер контейнера.
Чтож, тогда буду пробовать, наверно недонастроил что-то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в блокировке брандмауэром ufw.
Решение: sudo ufw allow 3306